# simple version of: error: 'x' does not name a type

Tags: c++, arduino

I have this class for Arduino:

```
#include <ADXL362.h>
#include <SPI.h>

#ifndef holyGraal_H
#define holyGraal_H

class holyGraal {
private:
  ADXL362 adxl;
public:
  holyGraal();
};

#endif
```

The .cpp is as follows:

```
#include "holyGraal.h"

holyGraal::holyGraal() {
}
```

The "main" program has setup and loop, but both are empty. When I try to compile it, I get the error:

```
In file included from holyGraal.cpp:1:
holyGraal.h:9: error: 'ADXL362' does not name a type
```

I don't understand. Why the include  doesn't define ADXL362 for my class? I did read the "How to make a Library Tutorial for Arduino", that is so often referenced to. I am not trying to make a library, just a class to use withing my project.

Comment: Are you sure that it's including the ADXL362.h that you *think* it's including?

Comment: You might want to read the `<ADXL362.h>` header file to see what it really contains?

Comment: I am sure ADXL362.h defines the ADXL362. If I start a new sketch and include it, I get no problems instantiating an ADXL362 object.

Comment: Are you sure the compiler successfully included `ADXL362.h`?  And are you sure you don't accidentally have another file named the same thing elsewhere in your include path?  (Note:  If you're on Windows, filenames are case-insensitive, so `adxl362.h` and `ADXL362.h` look the same to the compiler.)

Comment: How can I be sure of that?

Comment: If it didn't successfully include it, you'd have an error message to that effect.

Comment: Have a case sensitive search on "ADXL362" and find the error (or just respect some namespace)

Comment: If I add the include in the .ino file it works, but I still don't understand why the include I have now won't work